# The same PL/SQL function returns two different values

Tags: oracle

I have I PL/SQL function that checks if a Role has a privilege on a certain object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HasPrivilegeOnObject(rolename      IN VARCHAR2,
                                                objectname    IN VARCHAR2,
                                                objectowner   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                privilegename IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  output NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO output
    FROM dba_tab_privs
    WHERE
      grantee = rolename AND
      owner = objectowner AND
      table_name = objectname AND
      privilege = privilegename;

    IF output > 0 THEN
      output := 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN output;
  END hasprivilegeonobject;
```

To check it I do :

```
call dbms_output.put_line(HasPrivilegeOnObject('Role1','Table1','TableOwner','UPDATE'));
```

**the result is : 1;**

But when I run the same query as the one inside the function:

```
    select count(*) from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where 
        GRANTEE = 'Role1' and
        OWNER = 'TableOwner' and
        TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' and
        Privilege = 'UPDATE';
```

**The result is 0.**

Does anyone know what's wrong with that ?

Comment: In your function ObjectName "Table1" is taken for TABLE_NAME filter, however in the actual query it is takeing RoleName "Role1", hence I believe is the difference in the result.

Comment: In both cases parameter are different which may cause the o/p to be different.

Comment: That was actually a mistake when copying the query to Stackoverflow :) ! I edited the thread.

Comment: That's the problem with changing things for posting; its possible (and even likely in this case) that's there is something different in the values you're using in the two examples, but because you've changed them there's no way for us spot it. I'd guess you've got a typo or have swapped two fields over, but it can only be a guess alas.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton, as per your post it's not possible the result to be different. As Alex said, check for typo (OR) if there any space in the input (I mean " table1" instead of `table1`).

Comment: Can you add a debug in your function to see the actual value of the output before the if clause?

Comment: Add "where rownum <= 1" to the query, and then there's no need for the "if Output > 0 ..." code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you are using uppercase for object names, even when passing object names as arguments, unless you specifically created the objects with double quotes.  If you don't use double quotes when creating an object name, object names are stored as uppercase internally.**

You aren't initializing Output - the return value of the function.  What will happen if the query does not match any rows?  This means the return value could be indeterminate.

Unless you specifically used double quotes to name Table1 as Table1 (when Table1 was created), then Table1 would be stored internally, in the data dictionary as TABLE1.  This means the query in the function might not necessarily match any rows if it were called with an ObjectName (table name) argument of 'Table1'.

It is also not required, but is a good idea to add an exception handler in the function to make sure an exception is not preventing the return value from being completely set as intended..

Comment: Although I agree about the upper-case issue, the values have been replaced in the posted version so it's not clear if that's actually a cause, though it could well be (see my previous comment *8-). Not initialising `output` isn't a problem though; `count(*)` has to return a value into that variable. If the query was failing somehow then the function would throw an exception - adding a handler ('when others`!?) would be more likely to mask the problem than help identify it, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hi.. I rechecked the post and I am still seeing the post has Table1 which is not in uppercase; it may have been updated since I checked now; I have noticed that ORACLE will not throw an exception if a PLSQL query returns zero rows; if the query is syntactically valid and references valid objects, but does not match any rows, then no exception is thrown; I am trying to find out how this code would initialize in the case there are no matching rows.

Comment: Yeah, but the example is shown with `'Table1'` (etc.) for both the function call and the simple query; if it was (just) a case issue then both would find no grants. So either the real queries use upper-case names, or one does and one doesn't - but that is being hidden by the OP not having shown the actual, real, values being used. You're right in general, but I don't think we have enough information to say that's the problem here - though it may well be if inconsistent values are being used. And if there are no matching rows, `count(*)` still sets `output` to `0` - it can't *not* set `output`.

Comment: OK; but why does his post state the SQL SELECT (the non-PLSQL query) returns a count of zero ?  Wouldn't zero mean no match in the data dictionary?  That seems to be consistent with the table being internally named TABLE1, rather than Table1.  Does anyone know which of his queries is returning a nonzero count with Table1 (and not TABLE1)?  Maybe I'm not seeing his latest updates yet.

Comment: Because `Table1` isn't the real table name; those values have been changed for the question. The queries should return the same count, *if* the values are the same. Therefore they aren't - but because they've been changed for the question (to hide the real schema I guess) it's not obvious what the OP has wrong in the real, unaltered, queries. Typo, wrong case, values not lined up with the right column - we can only guess.